# Excel VBA copy single value to variable column range

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy the value in A1 to E3:E5 across multiple sheets, such as 18+ sheets. The tables and columns count match except the value in A1 (different dates) and the amount of rows for each sheet. So each sheet will always have E number of columns, and the Date column will always be E.

```
DateToCopy
Variable 1  Variable 2  Variable 3  Variable 4  Variable Date
value       value       value       value       paste Date
value       value       value       value       paste Date
value       value       value       value       paste Date
```

What I had tried to make/use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDate()

Dim wsVar As Worksheet

For Each wsVar In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   With wsVar
       Dim lastRow As Long

        lastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        .Range("A4").Copy
   
    .Range("M6" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   
   End With
Next wsVar

End Sub
```

My code copies the correct date but only pastes it one time and really far down.. so i'm not sure what I am missing. I understood the code I made above as the **For Each** going through each sheet and the rest pasting down the entire column for each sheet.

Thanks!

Comment: put `.` in front of `Cells.Find` so `.Cells.Find`

Comment: I adjusted and placed the `.` but it still ends up only putting the date once and really far down.

Comment: `"M6" & lastRow` should be `"M6:M" & lastRow`

Comment: @ScottCraner I was ALMOST right... thought it was a loop for a second :p

Comment: But get rid of the whole copy past and just assign the value: `.Range("M6:M" & lastRow).Value = .Range("A4").Value`  It will save time not using the clipboard.

Comment: The only issue now is that it goes on the entire column of M instead of stopping at the last row. Everything else works well so far now, thank you.

Comment: Then you have some cell way down on your sheet somewhere with a value, as the find it finding the last row with a value.

Comment: You are right! I started with a fresh excel document and the issue is corrected. Thank you!